# Assign output of service to $scope.variable

Tags: angularjs

I have a service method that return the result of a rest query and I want to assign that returned object to `$scope.key`

```
KeyService.$inject = ['$uibModal', 'Restangular'];
    function KeyService($uibModal, Restangular) {
        var service = {};

        service.keygenModal = keygenModal;
        service.keygen = keygen;

        return service;

        function keygenModal() {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'partials/_keygen_modal.html',
                controller: 'KeygenCtrl',
                backdrop: 'static'
            });
        }

        function keygen(commonName) {
            Restangular.all('vpn/clients/' + commonName + '/keygen').post()
            .then(function(client) {
                console.log(client);
                return client;
            });
        }
    }


ClientCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'KeyService'];
    function ClientCtrl($scope, KeyService) {

        $scope.keygenModal = function() {
            KeyService.keygenModal();
        };
    }

KeygenCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', '$stateParams', 'KeyService'];
    function KeygenCtrl($scope, $uibModalInstance, $stateParams, KeyService) {

        $uibModalInstance.opened.then(function() {
            $scope.key = KeyService.keygen($stateParams.client);
            console.log($scope.key);
        });
    }
```

`console.log(client);` outputs the returned object as expected.

`console.log($scope.key);` outputs *undefined*

#### Edit

It works this way but I'm not sure that using $rootScope is a good practice:?

```
...
    function keygen(commonName) {
        Restangular.all('vpn/clients/' + commonName + '/keygen').post()
            .then(function(client) {
                $rootScope.key = client;
            });
    }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to return `Restangular` from function. Use `then` in controller to assign local scope variable

Service

```
function keygen(commonName) {
   return Restangular.all('vpn/clients/' + commonName + '/keygen').post()           
}
```

Controller

```
KeyService.keygen($stateParams.client).then(function(client){
    $scope.key = client
});
```

> not sure that using $rootScope is a good practice

No it's not good. Keep in mind that all scopes in application are derived from `$rootScope` so anything that is in `$rootScope` will get copied to all nested scopes in the app

Comment: actually using `resolve` of `$uibModal.open()` would be better way to do this .... then if request fails modal isn't sitting there with nothing in it and can handle rejection without modal there. Just a suggestion

Comment: @charlietfi I agree and that's what I initially did but my request can take anywhere from 10-25 seconds so my modal has a spinner while the request completes. If I use resolve, the modal (w/ spinner) doesn't appear until the request is resolved; 10-25 seconds.

Comment: ok, understood :) changed my answer to use the modal's resolve anyway, might come in handy for other users with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `KeyService.keygen` is asynchronous. When you try to log the result to the console, it isn't resolved yet so it returns undefined. You need to resolve it using `then` in your controller or even better, if you need it to be resolved before your controller is initialized you can use the `resolve` object in your modal's definition. For example:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    resolve: {
        key: function ($stateParams, Restangular) {
            Restangular.all('vpn/clients/' + $stateParams.client + '/keygen').post()  
        }
    },
    controller: function ($scope, key) {
        $scope.key = key;
    }
});
```

There are more examples on using resolve on the ui-router wiki:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: This won't work in my case as the controller I want to use this in doesn't have a state associated with it.

Comment: Ow ok, assumed you we're using a state since you're injecting `stateParams`?!?!. Then you should resolve the promise in your controller like charliefl's answer.

Comment: right idea with resolve...more applicable to resolve of the modal though than of router

Comment: whoops overlooked that, thanks for pointing it out, i'll edit my answer